# Msql Insert,Fetch best practices

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I wanted to know what is the best way to fire insert statements to a DBMS.

- Is it better to first store all the values that you have say, scrapped from a website in a dataStructure like an ArrayList?
- Or is it better to do this in a loop, calling the insert statement for each row of data scrapped? The first approach will occupy some memory but will keep the connection open for comparetivley less time than the second approach.
- Also, is it a good practice to close the connection in the end of every iteration of the while loop? Or its better to keep the connection open during the entire loop and the close it once at the end?

Please help me in answering these questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are no definitive answers to your questions. **It depends** on a number of factors. To mention just a few:

- What Engine you're using
- What version of MySQL you're on
- How is MySQL configured
- How many rows you're inserting
- How many indices do you have in the target table?
- etc.

Here is a good reading [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html). Here is short extract:

> The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following
>   factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:
>   - Connecting: (3)
>   - Sending query to server: (2)
>   - Parsing query: (2)
>   - Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
>   - Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
>   - Closing: (1)

Therefore here are some hints if you care the most about the speed of inserts not about concurrency:

- Keep the number of roundtrips to the database (connections) to a minimum, preferably one
- Keep the number of INSERT statements to a minimum, preferably one
- If using multiple INSERT statements consider to wrap them all or batches in (a) transaction(s)
- If you issue INSERTS in a loop use prepared statements
- Learn and use optimizations specific to the engine you're using
- In some circumstances when you do a lot of inserts it might be beneficial to drop indices before and recreate them after you done with inserts